# Android NDK - Undefined reference to Android::Mutex, Android::AudioTrack

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm getting strange undefined references at link time for Android::Mutex and Android::AudioTrack used by a project I have taken over.

Does anyone have any ideas? There is no Android static library to include is there?

SharedLibrary  : ********jni.so

```
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:29: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::Mutex()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:29: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::~Mutex()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:232: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::lock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `~Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:234: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::unlock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:232: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::lock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `android_mute':
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:263: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::mute(bool)'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `~Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:234: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::unlock()'
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:234: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::unlock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:232: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::lock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `android_resume':
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:255: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::start()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `~Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:234: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::unlock()'
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:234: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::unlock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:232: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::lock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `android_pause':
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:247: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::pause()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `~Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:234: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::unlock()'
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:234: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::unlock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `android_get_delay':
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:237: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::latency() const'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:232: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::lock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `android_uninit':
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:220: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::stop()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:228: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::~AudioTrack()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `~Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:234: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::unlock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:232: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::lock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `android_start':
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:197: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::initCheck() const'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:198: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::start()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:201: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::setVolume(float, float)'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `~Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:234: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::unlock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `android_start':
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:207: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::~AudioTrack()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:232: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::lock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `android_init':
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:122: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::AudioTrack()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `~Autolock':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/threads.h:234: undefined reference to `android::Mutex::unlock()'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `android_init':
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/LibPlayer/amadec/audio_out/android_out.cpp:139: undefined reference to `android::AudioTrack::set(int, unsigned int, int, int, int, unsigned int, void (*)(int, void*, void*), void*, int, android::sp<android::IMemory> const&, bool, int)'
/Users/kevin/Desktop/player2/videoplayer/videoplayer/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libamadec.a(android_out.o): In function `~sp':
/Android/source/frameworks/base/include/utils/RefBase.h:378: undefined reference to `android::RefBase::decStrong(void const*) const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This plagued me as well - but I finally resolved it by linking with Bionic's header (`bionic/libc/include`), and - the important part - `#define`'ing `HAVE_PTHREADS` (i.e. add `LOCAL_CFLAGS += HAVE_PTHREADS`).

Answer (score 1):

Well these are some strange errors...
It looks like every time you reference something from the android::Mutex or the android::AudioTrack libraries the linker is unable to find those functions.  All I can say is that since those libraries are not part of the android standard library, make sure you have them in your build path, otherwise best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for the reply... Their header files are, but which actual .so / .a libraries contain them? libmedia.so is for the AudioTrack, but including it made no difference.

Comment: without seeing your source its hard to say.. make sure you have an instance of an object that has access to those functions..  The only other thing I can think of is perhaps those headers make calls into other classes that are not included in your project.  It seems like some of the reference errors are in the included classes.  Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Comment: But this is at link time, they should be included already. I tried adding link flags of -landroid and -lmedia without success.

Comment: link time is when the linker goes out and attempts to resolve all of the external variables you have referenced in your program.  It is unable to resolve all of those external references that it printed out, so you need to tell your linker where those classes are stored on your computer.  If you are in visual studio, that is real easy to do.  But if you did not reference the functions that the linker cannot find, there is some other library you need to include in your project that your current libraries depend on.

Comment: It has the classes, but it needs the shared libraries right>?

Comment: yes, you need to include not only the classes you are using, but also all of the classes that those classes use.  So if you include the entire library that android::Mutex and android::AudioTrack are part of, and the linker knows where it is.. you are good to go.

Comment: Yes I've included those as libmedia and libandroid / libc. So I don't understand why its not linking.

Comment: make sure your target platform is 2.3 or later. also if your using android-opencv, i don't believe that is supported any longer.. just racking my brain here.