# Which android library provides android::Mutex?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android NDK - Undefined reference to Android::Mutex, Android::AudioTrack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984001/android-ndk-undefined-reference-to-androidmutex-androidaudiotrack)

Does anyone know which shared library the Android NDK provides android::Mutex?

Kevin